# Azure Functions with time-triggering how to testing locally

Tags: typescript, azure-functions, postman

How to test Azure functions written in TypeScript, with time-triggering on demand?

I can do that with next steps:

1. open VS Code
2. open folder/project
3. start debugging/testing with npm run or npm run start
4. Ctrl+Shift+P to open the Command Palette
5. Type - Execute Function now
6. Chose the function - function immediately  starting

But - How can I do that in PostMan for example or a similar application?
In PostMan for example, I tried with

> http://localhost:7071/admin/functions/theNameOfTimeTriggeredFunction

but this gave me only JSON with function properties...

Answer (score 1):

> But - How can I do that in PostMan for example or a similar
> application? In PostMan for example, I tried with

If you mean time trigger, then it is not possiable. timer trigger didn't offer endpoint to let others such as postman to access.